# Azure DB PAAS or sql server VM on Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

We have existing Web application which has following layers

1. **Web Layer (Asp.Net MVC )**   **Sql Server 2012**   **SAP ETL services**: ETL
   jobs pulling the data from different datasource to  sql server

We have QA,STAGE,Production environment for the application.

We are planning to migrate the application to AZURE PAAS.For Web layer there is no issue's in migrating to PAAS. 
For DB Layer we have used microsoft migration steps using visual studio there is no issues at data base design level.
the only concern moving DB to PAAS is SAP ETL service and application jobs which is dumping millions of data to database. Not sure about how many DTU's it will consume.

Just need help to decide for the above scenario is it good to move DB to PAAS or have Sql server VM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be best for you to make some tests and base your decision on the results. For example, create an Azure Sql Server (Standard S0) and see how that performs. A great benefit of the PaaS offering, as you probably know, is that many aspects are handled for you automatically - upgrades, you can easily switch to another performance level, DB backups and restored, etc.

There is a very good article which can give you some additional pointers on how you can evaluate the pros/cons in your situation - [Choose a cloud SQL Server option: Azure SQL (PaaS) Database or SQL Server on Azure VMs (IaaS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas)

I would personally choose the PaaS option. I have used Azure Sql Server for a long time and I never want to go back to configuring and supporting my own SQL server.

Comment: We are working on setting up database migration. Will share our findings